# Getting function by name in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Code:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>


typedef INT (WINAPI * lolMessageBoxA)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT);



int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    lolMessageBoxA UchwytMessageBoxA;

    UchwytMessageBoxA = lolMessageBoxA(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("User32.dll"),"MessageBoxA"));

    UchwytMessageBoxA(NULL,"TEST WINDOWS","TEXT 2", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING);
    return 0;
}
```

When i called MessageBoxA normally before making hook the hooking part worked good. But when i erased that part and leaved only the 'hooking' part it fails...

Solved:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>


typedef INT (WINAPI * lolMessageBoxA)(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,UINT);



int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    lolMessageBoxA UchwytMessageBoxA;
    LoadLibraryA("User32.dll");
    UchwytMessageBoxA = lolMessageBoxA(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("User32.dll"),"MessageBoxA"));

    UchwytMessageBoxA(NULL,"TEST WINDOWS","TEXT 2", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug it? Did you check that `GetProcAddress` doesn't return NULL? And elaborate on "it fails".

Comment: As everyone else has said, you by no means need to load user32.dll. If you want to use WinApi, include `windows.h` and link to the library using the  `-mwindows` flag

Comment: @Evan Carslake That wasn't the case. I only wanted to load one specific library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As presented here, there's no reason for the process to have loaded `user32.dll`. So the call to `GetModuleHandle` will return `NULL`. Then the call to `GetProcAddress` will also fail and return `NULL`. And well, you can see what happens next.

When you called `MessageBoxA` directly, the linker would have produced an import table that forced the loader to load `user32.dll`. But when you removed the call to `MessageBoxA`, there was no need for it to do so.

You should replace the call to `GetModuleHandle` with a call to `LoadLibrary`, and so force the library to be loaded.

Finally, the real reason for you having asked this question is that your code neglects error checking. Don't do that. Check the values returned by the Win32 function calls. Had you done so you would have been able to work this out for yourself.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but user32.dll is generally loaded in every process anyway. It's like kernel32.dll. Only NT processes might not have loaded it. Unless it gets loaded the first time you do anything with dialogs/event loop etc. Then it wouldn't have been loaded immediately after WinMain().

Comment: @sashoalm I see no reason for user32 to be loaded into this process. Which function from user32 would be called? Kernel32 is different. It is guaranteed to be loaded. Also, what is an NT process? Loading on demand can happen with delay load. But normally the import table determines which DLLs are loaded. If this program had a message loop, then user32 would have been loaded. But look at the code. This program calls GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress.

Comment: Well usually I always see it in Process Explorer for every process, that's all I meant. But maybe that's because pretty much any process is bound to have shown something UI-related like a window at some point.

Comment: @sashoalm It's exactly as I describe in my answer. The compiled program is not linked against user32 and so the loader doesn't load it. Either call `LoadLibrary` to load it, or call a function from user32, and the behaviour changes. You should not assume that a DLL is guaranteed to be loaded unless you have good reasons to do so. That most processes load user32 is not a good reason.